# Modify PHP script to publish pending posts to newsletter (wordpress)

Tags: php, post

Wordpress > Newsletter Plugin
I'm modifying the php script - I want to only include 'post_status' == 'pending' content in the newsletter.

I am PHP newbie and struggling here.

i've tried 
    if ('post_status') == ('pending');

but that throws an error.

and I've tried 
    $filters['post_status'] == ['pending'];

but that doesn't seem to do anything.

```
// This array will be passed to WordPress to extract the posts
$filters = array();

// Maximum number of post to retrieve
$filters['posts_per_page'] = (int) $theme_options['theme_max_posts'];
if ($filters['posts_per_page'] == 0)
    $filters['posts_per_page'] = 10;


// Include only PENDING posts
$filters['post_status'] == ['pending'];

// Include only posts from specified categories. Do not filter per category is no
// one category has been selected.
if (is_array($theme_options['theme_categories'])) {
    $filters['cat'] = implode(',', $theme_options['theme_categories']);
}

// Retrieve the posts asking them to WordPress
$posts = get_posts($filters);
```

then, when I generate newsletter in WP, I hope to only see blogposts labeled 'pending,' but I instead only get published posts.

Comment: try in_array or something like that, but == ist an compare oparator and have to write in an if state :)

Comment: $filters['post_status'] = 'pending';

Comment: hey @episch and Mathew - thanks!

Comment: $filters['post_status'] = 'pending'

Comment: works perfectly. thanks again!